# How to mock a method that takes callback object and invoker use callback to delegate result

Tags: android, mockito, junit4, rx-java, powermock

How to mock a method that takes callback object and invoker of this method use it to delegate result to other callback. Here in my scenario I am creating Rx Single from it.

**1. RecentDataModel.java**

```
public class RecentDataModel {

public void getRecentData(RecentDataAdapter recentDataAdapter) {
    // Get data from database
    // Invoke if success
    recentDataAdapter.onSuccess()
    // Invoke if error
    recentDataAdapter.onError()

}
}
```

**2. RecentDataAdapter.java**

```
public class RecentDataAdapter {
    onSuccess(List<String> recents);
    onError();
}
```

**3. RecentPresenter**

```
public class RecentPresenter {
public Single<List<String>> getRecentsSingle() {
    return Single.create(new Single.OnSubscribe<List<String>>() {
            @Override
            public void call(final SingleSubscriber<? super List<String>> singleSubscriber) {
                mRecentDataModel.getRecentData(new RecentDataAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(List<String> keywordList) {
                        singleSubscriber.onSuccess(keywordList);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
}
}
```

**4. RecentTestCase**

```
public class RecentPresenterTest {

    @Mock
    RecentDataModel recentModel;

    @Test
    public void testLoadRecent() {
        doAnswer(new Answer() {
            @Override
            public List<String> answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
                List<String> recents = new ArrayList<>();
                recents.add("Recent1");
        recents.add("Recent2");
                return recents;
            }
        }).when(recentModel).getRecentData(any(RecentDataAdapter.class));

        RecentPresenter recentProvider = new RecentPresenter(null, null, prefModel);

        Action1 onNextListener = mock(Action1.class);

        recentProvider.getRecentsSingle.subscribe(onNextListener);

        ArgumentCaptor<List<String>> listCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass((Class) List.class);

        verify(onNextListener, timeout(5000)).call(listCaptor.capture());
        assertNotNull(listCaptor.getValue());
        assertEquals(listCaptor.getValue().get(0), "Recent1");
    }

}
```

**Note:**

1. Not having access to RecentDataModel and hence can't introduce new method like: `List<String> getRecentData();`
2. Although method ResentPresenter.getRecentsSingle() is not doing any business logic. But it gets connected with other methods in the class to produce the output. So mocking RecentDataModel is necessary.
3. Test is failing in following line `"verify(onNextListener, timeout(5000)).call(listCaptor.capture());"` because while mocking I am providing `any(RecentDataAdapter.class)` due to which `singleSubscriber.onSuccess(keywordList);` never gets called.

Comment: Please let me know if more info needed on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you don't call your callback on your adapter. As the callback is never called, `Single.success` is never called. So the `Single` is not notified to the emited list. And then your verify timeout.

To fix the issue, you have to call the `onSuccess` callback method in your mock :

```
  doAnswer(new Answer() {
        @Override
        public Void answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
            List<String> recents = new ArrayList<>();
            recents.add("Recent1");
            recents.add("Recent2");
            invocation.getArguments()[0].onSuccess(recents);
            return null;
        }
 }).when(recentModel).getRecentData(any(RecentDataAdapter.class));
```

Comment: Thanks @dwursteisen. Do I need to type cast "invocation.getArguments()[0]" into "SingleSubscriber<? super List<String>>" for invoking onSuccess() on it. Please reply

Comment: Thanks dwursteisen its work for me like this: ((RecentDataAdapter) invocation.getArguments()[0]).onSuccess(recents);. Thanks you very much man.